# Почему при обращении к сайту по https кидает на страницу phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, https

Здравствуйте, подскажите как исправить:
Есть сайт, при обращении к нему по `http` открывается главная страница сайта.
НО
при обращении к нему по `https` в URL остается все тот же текст, однако открывается страница авторизации phpMyAdmin.

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Вирутальные хосты так настроены

Answer (score 1):

Комментарии к вопросу пока добавлять не могу, потому пишу в виде ответа.
Покажите свои конфиги. Это ВСЕ файлы из директории `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` и так же файл `/etc/apache2/sites-available/apache2.conf`.

Если у вас не apache, а nginx, конфиг файл nginx.conf находится в одной из трёх папок:

```
/usr/local/nginx/conf
/etc/nginx
/usr/local/etc/nginx
```